# How do I change the URL of a website in HTML?

Tags: html

I'm new to coding, especially HTML and CSS. I really need to know how to change my site's URL. For example, I have a URL automatically set to http://www.jsbin.com/edit?html,output. How can I add code into my editor (JSBin.com) using HTML to change it to let's say http://www.codeisawesome.com/thissiteismine?

Comment: You need to learn the basics of web development and HTTP.  In particular, you need a server.  Look at GitHub pages.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't necessarily a way to completely change the URL but you can upload your html code in a file to a web host like 000 host and x10 host where you can change the domain (the most important part of a URL)
this is an example of a x10 host link you could write:
(http://) (your domain).x10host.com/(your file)
this results in (your case):
http://codingisawesome.x10host.com/thisismysite 
**WARNING** most people may have the same opinion as you about coding so the domain for 000 host and x10 host may be taken already

Answer (score 0):

Since HTML and CSS is both client-sided, changing the URL is unfortunately not possible. To modify the URLs, you would have to use the .htaccess file, which you probably do not have access to, if you use jsbin.com